# Kohana 3.2 freeze on streaming video

Tags: video-streaming, kohana

my trouble is when I start to stream a video via kohana 3.2 hole website is frozen. In other words:

1) I start streaming by entering domain.com/stream/file.flv

2) File begins to download (or playing in flowplayer)

3) I can't seek in video, I can't go to any page such as domain.com, domain.com/foo, domain.com/bar, I can do nothing with my domain.

4) The only way to fix problem is to restart browser or wait until file fully downloaded.

My stream function is in separated controller that extends Controller. In this function the only thing I do is loading a file (no sessions, no authorizations).

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is not a problem of Kohana but of particular configuration of your web-server. For example it allows  only one connection at any moment of time.

You need to check server configuration if you have acces to it, or ask server admin.

You may use Firebug or Chrome's dev tools to see loading flow on Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the native session handler the problems is that for every `session_open()` the client can only call one page at a time. So until the stream petition is over the "freezed" petition won't finish.

One solution is using database session's plugin (provided by default on Kohana), or do not activate session on the stream petition (only apply if can be public).

Hope it helps.